# Error renewing cluster certificates: ETCD pods not coming up due to "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have a multi-master Kubernetes cluster with three etcd pods running on each node. Recently, the cluster certificates expired, and I used the command kubeadm alpha certs renew all to renew all the cluster certificates. After renewing the certificates, the ETCD pods are not coming up, and I'm encountering the following error:

health check for peer 2c2a564436018bd9 could not connect: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "etcd-ca")

2023-06-21 11:10:58.162142 I | embed: rejected connection from "10.218.30.182:11550" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")

I tried printing the peer.crt file, but I couldn't identify any issues. I also attempted to renew the ETCD peer certificates using kubeadm alpha certs renew etcd-peer, but it didn't resolve the problem.Can someone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: [primary master etcd log](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/files/11817266/etcd_pnmomv0314.log)
[Second master etcd log](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/files/11817268/etcd_pnmomv0315.log)